# Flink Checkpointing issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am having below set of operators in my flink program,

> Data source(kafka)**DS1** --> Map operator(convert kafka message to
> POJO class)--> keyed by operator--> windowing Operator--> Sink
> Operator (we have created custom sink operator which call an API and
> write to Database).

And the same DataSource operator is also been used by other operators and it writes to another Kafka topic.

> ```
> **DS1**-->    Map Operation--> windowing function--> sink Operator(Kafka producer)
> ```

All of the above operators run with parallelism = 3. while running the job none of the operator is able to complete its checkpointing and resulting into below failures,
**exceeded checkpoint tolerable failure threshold.**

Below is my snippet for configuring checkpoint,

> public static void initEnv(StreamExecutionEnvironment env){  env.setParallelism(3); env.enableCheckpointing(1000);
> env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
> env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(5000);
> env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(12000);
> env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
> env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime); }

can anyone please help me on this and explain me why any of the flink operators are not able to commit the checkpoints?

Comment: Probably checkpoint is timeout. Try to increase checkpoint timeout, and check the log from TaskExecutor.

Comment: Timeout is a likely explanation, but there could also be issues with your custom sink.